# gimp: layer size for several adjoinig images

Tags: gimp

I have four jpg images that I want to combine to one with Gimp. The final image should show the original images next to each other. I plan to place each image in its own layer, so they can be manipulated independently.

If I open the images via Open as Layers, they are placed one upon the other.  My first idea would be to resize the layers to be four times as wide and then move the images within their layer.  But the Gimp documentation says in 7.50.3. Resizing Layer: "You can't resize a layer to bigger dimensions than that of the image."

How can I compose the desired final image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it the other way with `Image>Canvas size`. Do not resize the layers (there is an option for this). You can get the required size by just appending `*4` to the horizontal size, Gimp will do the computation for you.

Then you can move the layers. Checking View>Snap to canvas edges may help you keep the images aligned.

You can quickly spread the layers horizontally with the Align tool (if the layers have kept their initial size):

1. Position the layers roughly with the Move tool, so they are in the intended left-to-right order, and that all layers have a visible part
2. `Tools>Transform tools>Align`
3. Set the selector to `Relative to Image`
4. Click on a first layer: this should add 4 marker squares in its corner
5. Shif-click on the 3 others to select them (they should also get marker squares)
6. Click the `Distribute targets evenly in the horizontal` button:

[image]